# Express Simple Auth doesn't work

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication

I made a simple login api , and whatever I send as parameters , It won't work correctly ,Here is my User Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true , unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Here's my code :

```
router.post('/login', (req,res,next) => {
  var usern = req.body.username;
  var passw = req.body.password;
  console.log(usern + " " + passw);
  if ( !usern || !passw ) {
    return res.status(400).json({'error': 'Bad Request'});
  } else {
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username},(user , err)=> {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({'error': 'No User Found'});
      } else if (user.password !== req.body.password ) {
        return res.status(401).json({'error': 'Auth Failed'});
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          'success': 'true'
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by **It won't work correctly** ? Do you get an error or what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: And what response do you get?

Comment: Always get 'Bad Request' Response, and if i comment the statement with '!usern || !passw ' , it always responses 200

Comment: @FarhanTahir Up here

Comment: can you log usern and passw to see if body data is coming to server

Comment: @Haawmed Can you share your body of the request ?

Comment: Check your body fields names and make sure you don't have any space in them. it could be something like **"username "** that might be causing it.

Comment: @FarhanTahir it won't show my 'Success' : 'true' status
it will send user data
and statements about if password is wrong won't work

Comment: @Haawmed Sorry didn't understand what you mean ? did the undefined got resolved and if yes what was the issue with it. ?

Comment: I see, @Haawmed Change your  findOne callback from **(user, err)** to **(err, user)**.

Comment: @FarhanTahir done, Thanks a lot ! 

Comment: @Haawmed what solved undefined issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this one in mine,

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
$authResult=Auth::attempt(['username'=>$request['username'],'password'=>$request['password']]);
 if($authResult){
return redirect()->intended();
  }
 else{
return redirect()->to(route('login'));
}
```